# Adding a new field/column to avro file

Tags: python, bigdata, avro

Suppose I have a Avro file and I would like to know how to add new field/column like timestamp to store the current system timestamp for each record in python.

I am trying to extract avro schema and append timestamp field_name and then add timestamp values column to data file.

I am new to python and avro. Can someone help me as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this using the [`fastavro`](https://github.com/fastavro/fastavro) library, you would first read the avro file to get the schema and the records currently contained in it:

```
import fastavro

with open('file.avro', 'rb') as fo:
    avro_reader = fastavro.reader(fo)
    schema = avro_reader.writer_schema
    records = list(avro_reader)
```

Then modify the `schema` to include the new field:

```
schema["fields"].append({
    "name": "timestamp",
    "type": "long",
})
```

Augment the records to add the new `timestamp` value:

```
for record in records:
    record["timestamp"] = new_timestamp
```

And finally write the new avro file:

```
with open('new_file.avro', 'wb') as out:
    fastavro.writer(out, schema, records)
```

You might also want to look into using a logical type for this value. See [the avro specification](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/spec.html#Timestamp+%28millisecond+precision%29) for more details.